# How to build ROS nodes with other libraries?

Tags: ros, library, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

If I want to compile and build an ROS node with some other third party libraries, how & where should I modify the ROS Makefile so those third party libraries can be linked into the ROS node? Are there related online documents to which I can refer?

With Many Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10550/how-to-build-ros-nodes-with-other-libraries?/) by [HZhu](https://answers.ros.org/users/814/hzhu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-07-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can share you one example:glut

CMakeLists.txt

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)

 include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

 

 # Set the build type.  Options are:

 #  Coverage       : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization, w/ code-coverage

 #  Debug          : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization

 #  Release        : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization

 #  RelWithDebInfo : w/ debug symbols, w/ optimization

 #  MinSizeRel     : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization, stripped binaries

 #set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)

 

 rosbuild_init()

 

 #set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory

 set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

 #set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory

 set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

 

 #uncomment if you have defined messages

 #rosbuild_genmsg()

 #uncomment if you have defined services

 #rosbuild_gensrv()

 

 #common commands for building c++ executables and libraries

 #rosbuild_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} src/example.cpp)

 #target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} another_library)

 #rosbuild_add_boost_directories()

 #rosbuild_link_boost(${PROJECT_NAME} thread)

 #rosbuild_add_executable(example examples/example.cpp)

 #target_link_libraries(example ${PROJECT_NAME})

 rosbuild_add_executable(glut_test src/glut_test.cpp)

 target_link_libraries(glut_test /usr/lib/libglut.a)

 target_link_libraries(glut_test /usr/lib/libglut.so)
```

glut_test.cpp

```
 #include <GL/glut.h>

 

 void renderScene(void) {    

     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

     glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

     glVertex3f(-0.5,-0.5,0.0);

     glVertex3f(0.5,0.0,0.0);

     glVertex3f(0.0,0.5,0.0);

     glEnd();

     glFlush();

 }

 

 int main(int argc, char **argv) {

     glutInit(&argc, argv);

     glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGBA);

     glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);

     glutInitWindowSize(320,320);

     glutCreateWindow("3D Tech- GLUT Tutorial");

     glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);

     glutMainLoop();

     return 0;

 }
```

---

Originally posted by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) with karma: 2570 on 2011-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HZhu](https://answers.ros.org/users/814/hzhu/) on 2011-07-10**:
Thanks a lot.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-07-10**:
It would be way better if you only specify "glut" as the linking here. Without the path and without the library file. CMake should figure those out as default and it is portable. Also you're giving both the static and the shared object - is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Depending on the library you look for, there might also be a nice CMake way (instead of hardcoding):
[CMake libraries](http://www.itk.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries).

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-07-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2